# Word for someone who tries to manage, or oversee everything

Tags: single-word-requests

I know a couple of people who have determined that they, for whatever reason, need to help guide other people through their lives. They always do things or suggest things to multiple people, usually disingenuously, in order to reach a desired outcome. This isn't necessarily to their benefit, but usually a mutual benefit or to the benefit of the "victim".

Looking for something other then overseer, if possible.

Comment: A few terms are possible, one with positive meaning might be a coach (or a perfectionist?). While a negative would be a [micro-manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromanagement).

Comment: A control freak, perhaps?

Comment: A busybody....?

Comment: I'd call such a person a PIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **[kibitzer](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=kibitzer&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)**, if you're open to informal terms.

> kibitz: *informal*
>
> To offer unwanted or meddlesome advice, such as that given by the spectator of a card game. [AHD]

Answer (score 3):

[Micromanage](http://i.word.com/idictionary/micromanage) might be the word you are looking for.

Comment: +1, but you might want to "nounify" this into *micromanager* for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest *meddlesome*, *officious* or, if you'd like a noun, *[buttinsky](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buttinsky)* -- a person given to butting in.  I like kibitzer a lot, but it's more passive than the couple you're describing.